# Boosting one queryset over another queryset

Tags: django, search, union, django-queryset

We are doing search in django and we have two query sets: one `AND` queryset and one `OR` queryset.

```
q_list = [Q(x) for x in predicates if x[1]]
_filter_AND = reduce(operator.and_, q_list)
_filter_OR = reduce(operator.or_, q_list)
_queryset_AND = queryset.filter(_filter_AND)
_queryset_OR = queryset.filter(_filter_OR).exclude(id__in=[c.id for c in _queryset_AND])
queryset = list(chain(_queryset_AND, _queryset_OR))
```

Now, when returning, data all the data is mixed. Also, I want to have the results from `AND` queryset to appear first.

Would anyone know how to do that in django?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "data is mixed"? Could you please provide a data sample, sample filters and expected output?